# Magento 2: Closing tabs on mobile view

Tags: magento-2.1

The product tabs on the product item page in Magento, how would I go making all the tabs collapsed by default on mobile view?

Answer (score 6):

Create a copy of the core details file in your local theme: `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{Theme}/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/details.phtml` and remove the `data-mage-init='{"tabs":{"openedState":"active"}}'` and add the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        require(['jquery', 'matchMedia', 'accordion'], function($, mediaCheck) {

            var detailsTabs = $('.product.data.items');

            mediaCheck({
                media: '(min-width: 768px)',
                // Switch to Desktop Version
                entry: function () {
                    detailsTabs.tabs({
                        openedState: "active",
                        collapsible: false
                    });
                },
                // Switch to Mobile Version
                exit: function () {
                    detailsTabs.tabs({
                        openedState: "active",
                        collapsible: true,
                        active: false
                    });
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Stevie-Ray it helps me.

Comment: Thanks for the solution brother, It's worked but how to keep first tab is open on load in mobile view?

Answer (score 0):

extend `tabs.js` from magento core to set the option `collapsible` to `true`. I think that should collapse them by default.

Comment: and in which file i has to be adjusted?

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/custom_js.html (check the docs for your version)

Comment: ou, thats not easy to do. My Version is 2.2.4

Comment: looks more difficult than it is really :)